# How to create a SuperAdmin via JUser?

Tags: user

I am trying to create a new SuperAdmin via JUser:

```
    $user = new \JUser(0);
    $user->set('password',\JUserHelper::hashPassword($password));
    $user->set('username','administrator');
    $user->set('groups',array(8));
    $user->groups = array(8);
    $user->save();
```

Is this the right way? Or should i try another way?

Comment: What ever you do, please be very careful creating a super user programatically. You make 1 single mistake in the rest of your code and you can say good bye to your site. Personally I'd suggest creating a registered user and performing some two factor authentication to change the user's group to super user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the email but apart from that it'd probably work. You shouldn't set the groups property directly, the setter right above it is fine. Also I would suggest using the getInstance method of juser rather than newing up manually. Also you should catch errors in case there's a duplicate email or something. There is also a chance that the usergroups have been messed with, eg if this was for a distributed component, but if you know the superuser is still id 8 then it's fine.

```
$user = \JUser::getInstance();
$user->set('id',0);
$user->set('password',\JUserHelper::hashPassword($password));
$user->set('username',$username);
$user->set('email', $email);
$user->set('usertype', 'deprecated');
$user->set('groups',array(8));
if (!$user->save()) {
    $error = $user->getError();
}
```

Here is the API reference for anyone reading this:
https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JUser.html